# Is it possible to set the DPI of an application programatically?

Tags: mfc, winapi, dpi

Is  it possible to set the DPI of an application programmatically or the DPI only possible to set through the system preference?

**Note:** My application's GUI is coded in MFC and .NET forms.

**Update:**
After some research I have found no way of doing this so I have to agree with the only answer here; it cannot be done.

Comment: The real DPI depends on the output device (screen, printer, etc), so it should be set at the output driver level. It doesn't make *sense* to set it on a per-Application basis.

Comment: @David Actually it does make sense. It's running on a device with touch screen and to make it more touch friendly I want to make everything bigger (with as little effort as possible). I do however want to keep the system DPI intact for windows and the other applications.

Comment: No it doesn't make sense, DPI is not a per-application setting or even an application-level concept. You will need to increase the size of all controls manually.

Comment: @David Ok, I agree, it doesn't really make sense since DPI is meant to reflect your screen resolution. My goal is to enable Vista's automatic application scaling without changing the scale of the whole system.

Comment: That should be @Roel. Sorry for any confusion.. :-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about the Windows system-wide setting that determines the ratio between the physical DPI setting (that depends on the physical screen + resolution), the simple answer is "you can't", at least, not on at the application level in a WinForms app.

What you *can* do, is add scaling code to your form, see [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185804/how-to-control-the-font-dpi-in-net-winforms-app) entry. Basically, set the `AutoScaleMode` to `ScaleMode.Dpi`. See the other entry for more info.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same effect the system-wide setting has but on my application only. In other words, I want to let windows auto-scale my application but I want the application to supply the DPI.