# Wrong X and Y location in C#

Tags: c#, location, point

I made a small 2D game in C# but here is the problem:

when I launch the game on my laptop with a resolution of 1366x768, or on a laptop with 1920x1080 it works as wanted(all intel graphics), but when I launch the game on my pc with a HD6850 and a resolution of 1920x1080 the coordinates (locations) are off, like half of what they should be like:

A pictureBox is supposed to be on point x100 and y100 but is on something like point x50 and y50.

I would like to know why this is happening and how I can fix it.

Thanks in advance

Edit: Yes, I am making points, how can I fix errors with DPI? for instance: pictureBox1.location = new Point(100, 100);

Comment: Are you setting the X,Y locations in code? Something like `myControl.Location = new Point(100, 100);`? If so, you're probably running into issues with DPI.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the DPI difference tricking you into thinking this?

Comment: How are you measuring that it is on point (50,50)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075802/creating-a-dpi-aware-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Graphics.PageUnit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.pageunit.aspx) or [Graphics.PageScale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.pagescale.aspx).

If either of these values differs between your laptop and your PC, adjust them.