# Visual Studio Windows Forms Controls are overlapping on different machines

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, overlapping

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 on a 64bits Windows 7 machine which has a screen monitor with 1080p resolution. I designed a window with the Designer in MS VS 2010. Looked good on that machine.

Now I try to run this project on my laptop (also MS VS 2010 and Windows 7 64bits), which has  probably a different system font and a different screen resolution.

This is the result: http://puu.sh/1ZoRs *(not talking about the red lables)*

I searched the internet for a [fix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229594.aspx), but nothing seems to help
Also tried to edit some properties and changing the fonts to systemfonts in code. No luck.

Why does this happen? What's the fix for this? Why doesn't the window/controls resize automatically to fit everything?

Comment: This is because your laptop has a different dpi (scale factor).  I don't know the solution, only the cause.  Perhaps that will help you search more.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075802/creating-a-dpi-aware-application

Comment: Okay, I will take a look at this when I get back on my PC and compare the DPI settings.