# VB.Net form fails at drawing?

Tags: vb.net, forms, resize, resolution

So I have been developing a small program that uses forms for the users to use. The normal output should look like this:

[image: Normal Display Output]

Although, some users have been encountering odd bugs that I believe don't come from my code, or at least indirectly. There are a few panels that I created which are outside the viewing range of the window and I move these panels to their intended place for users to see on the form loading. It's easier for me to develop with instead of having panels stacking one over another. This works fine on my PC and everything is in place and display as it should. However as I said, a few users have been encountering this strange display bug:

[image: Bug Display Output]

[image: Bug Display Output]

What I first thought was that it was a Windows 8 bug, as if there was a difference between W7 and W8 form drawing. But I had other users reporting the same problem which were running W7. The bug doesn't draw the form cutoff the same way for everyone also...

I checked and rechecked my code to see if I could find a clue of what it is... but clearly nothing is stating that things move or display this way.!

Thanks for further help, this has been killing my brain.

Comment: It seems that the hole thing is shifted to the right. Do you use anchors to controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be this [Creating a DPI-Aware Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075802/creating-a-dpi-aware-application) - either way you need to find a common thread between machines where it 'goes wrong'.  If you can reproduce on your own machine then paring down the form to the bare minimum would be the next step.

This is how you change DPI in Windows http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/443-dpi-display-size-settings-change.html

Comment: Indeed! I finally was was able to reproduce the problem. I set my display to 125% and the 'bug' was obvious. Now that I know the source of the problem, what would your advice be on how to proceed to make it compatible with any PC display setting?