# Window Contents/Size Changes (unwanted) On Different Resolution Monitors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm currently developing a game in C# for a University project and have 3 different Windows Forms that make it up. 
I was primarily developing the game on my main computer which has a monitor with the resolution of 1920x1080 and all of the elements in each window fit the window as they should. However, when I open it on the laptop I take to university which has a resolution of 1366x768 they don't fit the window and either go out of the visible area of the window or overlap.
I've set the windows to be a certain size and turned off resizing and the maximise button.

This image shows exactly what is happening:

[image: Game Window Problem]

The window shown above is set to 'FormBorderStyle: FixedSingle' and 'Size: 588, 470'.

Comment: I think this is a DPI problem. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075802/creating-a-dpi-aware-application

Comment: It's definitely a DPI problem related to the buttons/the images on the buttons as they are the only things affected it seems. I'll try some of the work arounds in the link you provided, thanks!