# Moving project between two different computers with different VGA card change the form size

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have problem once moving the project from one computer to the other. I am using Visual studio 2015. I am talking here about the project in design mode not in the running mode. Actually, I develop the project with my college and once he sends me the form, the size is different. We have put our screen resolution to be the same but his PC VGA card is more advance than me (he can have resolution more than 2000). If we put the form size in his PC (1360, 768) it will be (908, 502) once it is moved to my PC. If we put the size in my PC to (1360, 768), it will be much bigger once we try it in his PC. 
Any idea what is the problem here? Is there any specific parameter that we need set so it will stay as it is once we move it from one PC to another even if the PC's have different VGA card.

Comment: Could it be DPI settings are different? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4075802/1997232).

Comment: I would say the DPI as @Sinatr but have you considered refactoring your way of designing so it is more responsive?