# VS 2015 munging winforms on my devel laptop

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

VS 2015 (and 2013 for that matter) is badly mangling my WinForms in the Designer. It's resizing this form in particular and squishing everything down forcing me to remake the form repeatedly.

[image: Mangled Winform]

Seems to happen only when I compile on my laptop. Any settings I'm missing?

Comment: It looks like the DPI has caused issues. [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075802/creating-a-dpi-aware-application) has some great information on what you can do to try and work around this.

Comment: Ahh @Equalsk you are a genius! Following the advice on that link I added this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(96F, 96F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi; to the WinForm in question. Problem solved thanks