# Winforms Scaling and Cutting Issue in Screens with Different Resolutions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I have a desktop app that is developer for Windows operating Environment.The App was developed on a 1,280x720 Monitor.It works very well on most systems with normal screen resolutions.Including 1080P and old 17 and 15 inch monitors.

The thing is when it comes to Laptops with 15" screen and 1080P resolution,the App shows up correctly at first but after using a control,the window gets smaller.The Text gets larger and some controls fall on top of others.

Another issue is that when the user has adjusted this size setting to High

[image]

The app window gets Cut and it does not show the complete content.The Application is not full screen.
One user was using a Windows Surface Pro and to get the Application Fit,the above setting was reduced.But this made the App too small,so the user ended up getting a refund.

I'm not targeting Tablet(Surface Pro) users.The intended audience is desktop Users.

What is the best way to tackle this issue keeping winforms GUI.

Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're looking for the AutoScaleMode property. This will allow your controls to change size according to the zoom level of your users' PCs (which you pictured above).

There is some really good advice in this answer to ['Creating a DPI aware application'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075802/creating-a-dpi-aware-application). But basically:

- Set the AutoScaleMode of your base control (the Form) to `Font` or `Dpi`
- Remove as many custom font settings from your controls as possible (this will restore them to the default MS Sans Serif at ~8pts)

Develop the app at the standard zoom level and then test it on larger screens with higher zooms, see how it goes.

Hope this helps