# Visual Studio Design View looks nothing like the program when it gets run

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

[image: design view vs actual view]

As you can see I have had to make the design view look terrible to get the desired output for the actual program. When I originally made the form I made it so it looked similar to the one on the right (in the picture) and the form came out like 4X the size of the screen with things way apart from each other.

My shitty solution was to bring everything closer in the design view and you can see what that produces in the picture.

Is there a way to set design view to 100% so it is exactly what you get when you hit run?

Comment: Are you on a high-res display by chance? The designer is not DPI aware, but the application at runtime is, so it's probably auto-scaling. Aside from your answer to that for next steps, my next suggestion would be to use the flexible layout containers to help line things up, decide whether controls autogrow or stay static, anchor to various places, etc., instead of absolute positioning things all over the form.

Comment: You may want to have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075802/creating-a-dpi-aware-application

Comment: @Aron unfortunately I am stuck using this for this course I am doing.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ YEs my laptop is high res, never heard of flexible layout containers so might have to take a look