# Blurry/odd text in winforms - cleartype/scaling issue?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10

I developed an winforms program on w8 and just tried it on w10 for the first time, the following image shows how the text looks in the forms editor of vs2015 versus how it looks when the program is executed.

[image: Two windows, one with blurry text]

The text in the title bar renders fine.

I should probably mention I'm at 4k resolution with 150% scaling - I tried all the autoscalemode options and none did the job.

There seem to be ways to deal with this in wpf but in winforms I can't find any information, which is odd because this is presumably a common thing.

Comment: There's some new support added to .Net 4.7 for high DPI with Windows Forms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms This *might* be relevant.

Comment: _"this is presumably a common thing"_ -- yes, it is common. So common, that Stack Overflow has _many_ questions with answers already addressing just this problem. Standard scaling issue. Make your app dpi-aware, otherwise Windows just has your program render at a smaller size and scales it up. See marked duplicate for more info.

Answer (score 2):

This is known issue - you need to develop your WinForms app to be a DPI-aware.

Read here for example and detailed explanation: [Creating a DPI-Aware Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075802/creating-a-dpi-aware-application)

Generally, you need to apply a specific `Forms` design rules to make them DPI-independent.