# Quality loss in Run mode against Design Mode in application

Tags: c#, winforms

When I have created any application, all things is OK.
But when I run it, quality reduced!
In addition, size of forms or controls and design of them is currept. Also about alignment and anchors. bellow pictures show the problem.

[image: A sample of quality loss]

[image: Another sample of quality loss]

Albeit this happen just in my system. In other system that works truly.
I tried it in virtual machine. It works truly but after a time, quality reduced too. By restore the windows, it is OK,  but after a time, quality reduced again!
Where is the problem?

**Edit:**

In other language and platforms such as ASP.net or Qt, this problem doesn't exist.

Comment: It looks to me like your current DPI / display scaling settings are the culprit here; Windows Forms is known not to play nicely with higher DPI displays. If you don't want to switch to a more modern GUI framework like WPF, then you may have to try some workarounds to get your Windows Forms application to scale correctly. [This question here might be able to help you with that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075802/creating-a-dpi-aware-application)

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherKyleHorton . In display settings, scale of text, apps, and other items has been fixed to 125%. I changed it to 100% and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Also, by putting below code to designer.cs, in scale 125% it works correctly!

this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);

Comment: Glad to hear that worked for you! You may want to add an answer to your own question detailing the steps you took and accept it once you are able.

Comment: OK @ChristopherKyleHorton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By thanksgiving of @ChristopherKyleHorton that help me to find the answer, it is a problem with DPI.

In my display settings, scale of text, apps, and other items has been fixed to 125% (120 DPI). So, some of apps and items such as winform can't support this. For them, scale of text, apps, and other items must be 100% (96 DPI).

Also, if you don't like to change it, or your destination system use 125% too, you can add following code at the form.designer.cs in the initialize section:

```
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
```

This can solve the problem for ever.
Thanks @ChristopherKyleHorton.