# Winforms C# - Form Scaling Issue

Tags: winforms

("Citizen Developer" here) - I have a Winforms app I'm writing that is behaving strange when I run the application on my surface (same computer I'm using for development).  The main form and several others forms display correctly.  However, other forms when they load "shrink" to a very small size - the controls all scale down to that same size except for the datagridview control.  Once that form is loaded, all the other forms that displayed correctly before shrink down also.

I've tried setting all the properties of the form that causes the issue to the same as the one that works but it didn't help

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Thank you.  I tried the suggestions in that link but it made it worse.  Now all the forms are small and the scaling is wrong.

Comment: Make sure you set the Forms and Containers `AutoScaleMode` property to `Dpi`. Also, some more details help us to help you. What's the display scale of the developing environment? It must be `100%`. What's the .NET version of your app? .NET Framework 4x? Or .NET 6+? See this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4075802/14171304) for more tips.

Comment: Thank you! Adding the section to the app config file and setting the AutoScalemode property to Dpi helped.  The forms now load at normal sizes.  The scaling on some controls are a little off but we can live with it (in house app).  I read somewhere that putting the controls in a Table Layout Panel can help with that scaling.  Might try looking into that.  Thanks again.