# DPI Aware application in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, dpi, dpi-aware

I want to make my C# application DPI aware. There is a command available in Windows API called SetProcessDPIAware() but the problem is it only works in Windows Vista and higher versions of Windows and not in XP. How can I make the controls, Buttons and Fonts DPI aware such that it displays correctly regardless what ever Windows version is used?

Comment: What kind of C# application? Is this Windows Forms?

Answer (score 6):

Calling `SetProcessDPIAware` doesn't just magically make everything DPI aware for you; its purpose is to declare to Windows that your app has been correctly written to be DPI aware. Furthermore, its use is not recommended; you're supposed to declare DPI awareness in your manifest instead. There's an entire [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464660(v=vs.85).aspx) about this on MSDN.

Comment: Ok if i declare DPI awareness in manifest will it work for windows XP as well?

Comment: @zeemalik: There might be an easier solution. I'm not sure if you haven't noticed my comment above, but can you tell us what *kind* of C# application you're developing? Are you using Windows Forms (WinForms) or WPF?

Comment: We have a windows form application not WPF. How can i make the all the controls and fonts display correctly keeping in mind it can run on XP and higher versions of windows?

Comment: Can any one help in this regard?

Answer (score 2):

See my moderately detailed answer on how to make an application respond to DPI settings on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185804/how-to-control-the-font-dpi-in-net-winforms-app/202172#202172).

The short version is that you can change all your form's `AutoScaleMode` to `ScaleMode.Dpi`.

But it's better to leave it at `ScaleMode.Font`; fonts get bigger as the DPI increases.