# How to change appearance of winforms in vb.net as per Windows display setting?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to control the font DPI in .NET WinForms app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185804/how-to-control-the-font-dpi-in-net-winforms-app)

How to change the Appearance/UI of win-forms in vb.net as per Windows display setting?

default windows display setting is 100%, if i change it to 125% then my win-forms in my application doesn't display properly as per display settings.

can anyone help that how to do it?

Thanks,

Pradip Shinde.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `AutoScaleMode` for your forms to `Font` or `DPI` - the framework should handle scaling automatically.

If that doesn't help, details on what you mean by "doesn't display properly as per display settings" means. Screenshots would help, too.