# Why Forms Design changes between XP sp2 and XP sp3

Tags: c#, forms, windows-xp

i have an application in C#...
Why Forms Design changes between  XP sp2 and XP sp3 in C#?
Does the compatibility?
What is the solution to get similar Forms design in C#?

Comment: There should not be any difference. What differences are you exactly seeing?

Comment: in xp sp2 .. size of form changes and location for textbox and button in same form also changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a difference in the DPI setting in Windows that causes the change in your application.

Check this guide to see if you have a different value (standard is 96 dpi): http://www.lawfirmsoftware.com/support/change_dpi_settings_xp.htm

You will need to change your winforms app to be dpi independant. Take a look at this question for more help: [How to control the font DPI in .NET WinForms app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185804/how-to-control-the-font-dpi-in-net-winforms-app)