# Why does changing the DPI on the screen affect the layout of my dialog?

Tags: c#

I have a wizard that runs and looks beautiful (if I say so myself) the problem is on Windows XP this dialog gets severly messed up when the user changes the DPI of the font on their screen. It seems that the control it self is being moved. I honestly do not even know where to start with this.

[image: Wizard (correct) 96 DPI (Windows 7)]

[image: Wizard (wrong) 120 DPI Windows XP]

Comment: Sizes in dialogs are based on dialog units, which are affected by the DPI setting.

Comment: So how can I make a dialog that will size correctly given all of the DPI's?

Comment: Usually you use [`MapDialogRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645502.aspx) to get DPI-independent coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need make the dlalog's components aware of the DPI setting and calcualte the space and lay out needed. WPF does this automatically.

Here is an example on SO : [How to control the font DPI in .NET WinForms app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185804/how-to-control-the-font-dpi-in-net-winforms-app/202172#202172)

Have a read of [Writing High-DPI Win32 Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd464660%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)