# Local Report Rendering Font vs Windows DPI Settings

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, fonts, dpi

I have a C# program that uses .NET 2.0 Local Report Rendering to create an SSRS2005 designed PDF.

One of my users struggles to read text on 1280 x 1024 resolution, so instead of lowering her resolution, she changed her DPI settings to 125%.

When the report is generated on her PC and we open it up, the font is too large and the values are not entirely inside the columns.

Aside from returning DPI settings to 100% and rather lowering her resolution for her, is there any way to programmatically cater for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I could find was [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371771(v=vs.85).aspx) white paper from Microsoft. They basically tell you to make your app "High DPI Aware" by doing some checks and adjusting your GUI accordingly.

---

More info at the following Stack Overflow links:

[Creating a DPI-Aware Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075802/creating-a-dpi-aware-application)

[How to control the font DPI in .NET WinForms app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185804/how-to-control-the-font-dpi-in-net-winforms-app)

Comment: I guess I'll have to build in a check and make another RDLC file (with a smaller font) for these circumstances...