# How to make at panel couple pictures to one

Tags: c#, winforms, image

I need to make 4 different images in one, and it will be in the panel. Panel size will vary from 180 to 320. I tried to do one main panel, and in her place 4, which are fixed by anchors...

What I have (source four pics)

[image]

What i need to get. Panel like this

[image]

What I got

[image]

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel main_panel = new Panel();
        main_panel.BackColor = Color.Azure;
        Panel panel_top_left = new Panel();
        Panel panel_top_right = new Panel();
        Panel panel_bottom_left = new Panel();
        Panel panel_bottom_right = new Panel();

        Bitmap btm_msg_panel_top_left = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.blue_t_l);
        panel_top_left.BackgroundImage = btm_msg_panel_top_left;
        Bitmap btm_msg_panel_top_right = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.blue_t_r);
        panel_top_right.BackgroundImage = btm_msg_panel_top_right;
        Bitmap btm_msg_panel_bottom_left = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.blue_b_l);
        panel_bottom_left.BackgroundImage = btm_msg_panel_bottom_left;
        Bitmap btm_msg_panel_bottom_right = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.blue_b_r);
        panel_bottom_right.BackgroundImage = btm_msg_panel_bottom_right;

        main_panel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
        panel_top_left.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
        panel_top_right.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left;
        panel_bottom_left.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left;
        panel_bottom_right.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;

        main_panel.Controls.Add(panel_top_left);
        main_panel.Controls.Add(panel_top_right);
        main_panel.Controls.Add(panel_bottom_left);
        main_panel.Controls.Add(panel_bottom_right);

        panel1.Controls.Add(main_panel);
    }
```

Comment: If I am not wrong then you need each panel completely joined to each other,I mean there should be no gap between any of the panels.Isn't it ?

Comment: I tried your code and it's working perfectly.It is difficult to get what you problem is.I think it would be better if you post the image of what you are getting.

Comment: @Aviral Singh I posted a new pic in my question

Answer (score 1):

Well... I will answer on my own post :))

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel panel_top_left = new Panel();
        Panel panel_top_right = new Panel();
        Panel panel_bottom_left = new Panel();
        Panel panel_bottom_right = new Panel();


        Bitmap btm_msg_panel_top_left = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.blue_t_l);
        panel_top_left.BackgroundImage = btm_msg_panel_top_left;
        Bitmap btm_msg_panel_top_right = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.blue_t_r);
        panel_top_right.BackgroundImage = btm_msg_panel_top_right;
        Bitmap btm_msg_panel_bottom_left = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.blue_b_l);
        panel_bottom_left.BackgroundImage = btm_msg_panel_bottom_left;
        Bitmap btm_msg_panel_bottom_right = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.blue_b_r);
        panel_bottom_right.BackgroundImage = btm_msg_panel_bottom_right;


        panel_top_left.Width = btm_msg_panel_top_left.Width;
        panel_top_right.Width = btm_msg_panel_top_right.Width;
        panel_bottom_left.Height = btm_msg_panel_bottom_left.Height;
        panel_bottom_left.Width = btm_msg_panel_bottom_left.Width;
        panel_bottom_right.Height = btm_msg_panel_bottom_right.Height;
        panel_bottom_right.Width = btm_msg_panel_bottom_right.Width;


        panel_top_right.Location = new Point(panel_top_left.Width - panel_top_right.Width, 0);
        panel_bottom_left.Location = new Point(0, panel_top_left.Height - panel_bottom_left.Height);
        panel_bottom_right.Location = new Point(panel_top_left.Width - panel_bottom_right.Width, panel_top_left.Height - panel_bottom_right.Height);


        panel1.Controls.Add(panel_bottom_right);
        panel1.Controls.Add(panel_top_right);
        panel1.Controls.Add(panel_bottom_left);
        panel1.Controls.Add(panel_top_left);
    }
```

This is result

[image]

Comment: Check the value `Form.AutoScaleMode` property. If it's `Dpi` or `Font`, try changing your OS font size or DPI setting to make sure that the layout stays correct on other systems. For example, Windows XP has a default font of a different size than Vista, meaning that .NET will autoscale your contents to try to make your app "DPI-aware" as you move your app between these two systems. There are several answers on SO which deal with autoscaling ([this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4076259/69809), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/202172/69809)).

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps;

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel main_panel = new Panel();
        main_panel.BackColor = Color.Azure;
        Panel panel_top_left = new Panel();
        Panel panel_top_right = new Panel();
        Panel panel_bottom_left = new Panel();
        Panel panel_bottom_right = new Panel();

        Bitmap btm_msg_panel_top_left = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.blue_t_l);
        panel_top_left.BackgroundImage = btm_msg_panel_top_left;
        Bitmap btm_msg_panel_top_right = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.blue_t_l);
        panel_top_right.BackgroundImage = btm_msg_panel_top_right;
        Bitmap btm_msg_panel_bottom_left = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.blue_t_l);
        panel_bottom_left.BackgroundImage = btm_msg_panel_bottom_left;
        Bitmap btm_msg_panel_bottom_right = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.blue_t_l);
        panel_bottom_right.BackgroundImage = btm_msg_panel_bottom_right;

        main_panel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
        panel_top_left.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
        panel_top_right.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
        panel_bottom_left.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
        panel_bottom_right.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left;

        main_panel.Controls.Add(panel_top_left);
        main_panel.Controls.Add(panel_top_right);
        main_panel.Controls.Add(panel_bottom_left);
        main_panel.Controls.Add(panel_bottom_right);

        panel1.Controls.Add(main_panel);
    }
```

Comment: Aviral Singh, at least provide some documentation as to your changes and what result you received from them. :(