# Visual Studio 2013 form control alignment issue on Windows 8

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I created a Windows application in VS 2013 on W7. It's running great and no issue but recently I bought a new W8 laptop and tried to run the application on W8. All my controls are misaligned and some overlap. `AutoScaleMode` is set to Font for each form.

Examples:
  [image]
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not Windows 8 that's the problem, but a higher [DPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) setting.

The best option would be to switch over to [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but the problem can be mitigated with some care. You might consider a `TableLayoutPanel` for this application (it looks table-ish to me).

If you can't/won't use a layout panel, set the [`AutoScaleMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of your form (and other containers, like `Panel`s) to `Font`. If that doesn't work, try `Dpi`. See [the MSDN page on that enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Further StackOverflow reading (or "works cited"): ["Creating a DPI-Aware Application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075802/creating-a-dpi-aware-application) and ["How to control the font DPI in a .NET WinForms app"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185804/how-to-control-the-font-dpi-in-net-winforms-app)